# converting complex malloc() to new() and suggsest good method to easily convert complex malloc

Tags: c++, c

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *right,*left;
};

// A queue node
struct Queue
{
    int front, rear;
    int size;
    node* *array;
};

// A utility function to create a new tree node
node* newNode(int data)
{
    node* temp = new node();
    temp->data = data;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

// A utility function to create a new Queue
Queue* createQueue(int size)
{
    Queue* queue = new Queue();

    queue->front = queue->rear = -1;
    queue->size = size;

    **queue->array = (struct node**) malloc(queue->size * sizeof( struct node* ));**

//this is the malloc statement which i want to convert to new;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        queue->array[i] = NULL;

    return queue;
}
```

i'm unable to convert that malloc() statement in createQueue function to new();
need help.
and also please suggsest me a good method to convert that complex malloc() statements to new() for the next time.

Comment: new can be called on C++ objects. Are you trying to instatiate an object of some sort?

Comment: Using `**` to mark the code you want to change is a huge mistake in asking this question, since it has meaning when prefixed to that statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing with that `malloc` call is to allocate an array of pointers to `node`.

To allocate an array dynamically in C++ you use `new[]` like

```
queue->array = new node*[queue->size]{};
```

The above statement allocates an array of `queue->size` pointers to `node`, and also default initializes each pointer, which means they will all be null-pointers (so you don't need the loop after the allocation).

And remember that everything you allocate with `new[]` must be deallocated with `delete[]`.

---

Now that we solved your problem, the *proper* solution is to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of dynamically allocate memory like you do.

I would also recommend you don't use pointers, but instances of the structures instead. Both for the vector, and also more generally. Besides polymorphism, there's rarely a need to use pointers in modern C++.

Comment: thankyou @Some programmer dude, your solution explains me everything i wanted to know.